# How to use git svn clone on any random folder in svn repository

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn

Our SVN repository has grown very big and due to malpractice, we are now working on one of the branch deep down.

Our structure is

```
Repo/
   tags/
   branches/
   trunk/
```

What i want is to create git repository for following folder only

```
Repo/
  branches/identifier1/identifier2/src/
```

I do not want any other folders (as tags/ is very big, trunk/ is very big, and other folders are also very big in size).

I am not able to achieve that. I have tried following (and various other combinations)

```
git svn clone <Repo>/<path to branch> 
git svn clone <repo> -branches <path to branch>/*
git svn clone <repo> -T <path to branch?
```

In all my attempt, either there is error or empty repository with warnings. 
Once it seems succeeded when i tried to clone entire repository, but then stopped due to size/time constraints.

Once i get over this initial hump, my plan is to work on git locally, and push to svn repo instead of usual svn commit.

Comment: `git clone` operates on existing git repos, what steps did you take to initialize the git repo from your svn repo?

Comment: "Once i get over this initial hump, my plan is to work on git locally, and push to svn repo instead of usual svn commit." ... Talk about malpractice...

Comment: there was typo. I used git svn clone